# Putting a Bitmap as Extra in a result Intent closes App completely

Tags: android, android-intent

When I return to the main activity from another activity and put a bitmap extra in the return Intent, the app finishes completely and onActivityResult in the main Activity is not called at all.

**SecondaryActivity.java**

```
private void returnFromModule(int result) {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.putExtra(CameraModule.Keys.KEY_FILE_PATH, mFilepath);
    //if the next line is omitted the app goes back normally to the main activity
    intent.putExtra("data", mThumbnail);
    setResult(result, intent);
    finish();
}
```

Note that everything works fine when i dont put a bitmap extra. The bitmap also isn't very large.

```
public static Bitmap getThumbnail(String filepath) {
    ExifInterface exifInterface = getExifInterface(filepath);
    byte[] thumbnailData = exifInterface.getThumbnail();
    Bitmap thumbnail = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(thumbnailData, 0, thumbnailData.length);
    return thumbnail;
}
```

This is the thumbnail Bitmap that is put in the intent.

**MainActivity.java**

Here is the onActivityResult of my MainActivity but i don't think it matters much since it isn't called at all when a Bitmap is put in the return Intent.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
           ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.path)).setText(data.getExtras().getString(CameraModule.Keys.KEY_FILE_PATH));
    }
}
```

}

here is how i start the SecondaryActivity

```
startActivityForResult(new Intent(this, SecondaryActivity.class),1);
```

Comment: Did you start SecondardActivity from MainActivity? If you do, did you start SecondardActivity by using startActivityForResult() to return intent to MainActivity? If you don't, you have to set class info when creating Intent like below answer.

Comment: Yes i started the activity for result. It finishes the app only if i add a Bitmap extra, otherwise it returns normally.

Comment: Its a very bad idea to return a bitmap. And it does not work as you can see. Better return the file path and let the receiver extract the bitmap.

Comment: Use try-catch to find out what goes wrong. What does the logcat tell you?

Comment: No exception is fired. Logging gives me no warning  or error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a size limit over what you can pass through activities. You can't do this.

Comment: I am running this with Android 6, shouldn't it fire  a TransactionTooLargeException ? The Bitmap is also just a Thumbnail and should go through since Bitmap implements Parcelable.

Comment: Please tell us the amount of bytes that you try to put in that intent.

Comment: The Bitmap is 0.786 Mb

Comment: This is not a good practice. Even if it looks small (how did you measure?), the transaction might fail if the transaction buffer is not empty. You should save to File and parcel an Uri, for example